# Can i convert char symbol to string

Tags: c++, string, char

Is there way to convert the symbol that char displays when you run the program like how 97 char is equal to "a" when you run the program into a string?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>
#include <random>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
int max = 122, min = 97;
int range = max - min + 1;
srand (time(0));
char letter = rand() % range + min;
cout << letter << endl;
string letter2;
cin >> letter2;
if(letter2 == letter)
{
cout << letter2 << endl;
}
}
```

This is the code I tried but it didn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer to the the question in your first paragraph is: not within the C program, you would have to assign a font to your terminal which used different glyphs for 97 etc.    I'm not sure what the code sample has to do with the question

Comment: Can you explain what your overall goal is here

Comment: Closest you should have is `if(letter2[0] == letter)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you could use an object of type std::string as letter. for example

```
std::string letter( 1, rand() % range + min );
```

Secondly you could use a character array as for example

```
char letter[2] = { char( rand() % range + min ), '\0' };
```

Or you could leave as is but the condition could look like

```
if ( letter2.size() == 1 && letter2[0] == letter )
```